# WhatsApp Web and the QR Code

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, qr-code

We connect to the WhatsApp web by scanning the QR code. When scanning like this, WhatsApp is transferring some data between the mobile and the web. So if a data transfer is going on,
what will that data be?
How is that data taken?
Can't we use that data to use the web without QR code scanning?
There is a reason to ask this, the camera on my phone does not work, so I can't scan the QR code and use the WhatsApp web. If there is an answer to this, please let me know.

Comment: The technical detail has been explained on our sister site [so] for programming: [Mechanism behind QR code scanning of WhatsApp web/desktop app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37350286/2821954)

Comment: The data is authentication & key negotiation between the web client and device.  You can't feed this data to the device without camera. WhatsApp only trusts QR code.